# Computational results for the sequence $n!+{p_n}!+1$ are, well, very very unusual

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, factorial

[Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) and I were discussing in a chat room and I thought that it would be nice to test the sequence $$n!+{p_n}!+1$$ for primality.

Then I wrote Peter that I expect much of primes in this sequence, well, at least the expression is formed in such a way that there *could* be much of them.

But, to my and Peter´s surprise, he computed and tested this sequence for all $1\leq n \leq 100$ and found that for only $n=3$ in that range the expression is prime.

He is pushing his computations even further, even at this moment, and, for me almost unbelievable is that he passed $n=800$ and found that only for $n=3$ the expression is prime and we are curious why there is (so far) only one prime although small factors are impossible for large values of $n$.

So, we agreed that a question about this unusuality should be asked, and I ask three of them, very much interrelated and connected and answerable.

> Do we have any explanation of why this sequence has, for the range computed, so a small number of primes? Is it naive to expect that this sequence has an infinite number of primes? What "should" be expected to happen in some very large ranges?

**Update**: No further primes up to $n=1000$.

Comment: I don't see how this problem can be tackled as we still don't know whether there are an infinity of prime Euclid numbers...

Comment: @Klangen Observe that I did not ask "Is there an infinite number of primes in this sequence?" I just asked "Is it naive to expect that this sequence has an infinite number of primes?"

Comment: I myself does not find it unusual. PNT and Stirling's formula state $p_n!=\Omega(e^{n\ln^2n})$ and the probability of $n$ being a prime is $1/\ln n$. Neglecting the badly-approximated inteval 1~10, $$\sum_{n=10}^{800} \frac{1}{n\ln^2n}\approx 0.29$$. About the constant term in big omega, I'm sure it is less than 1.

Comment: @KemonoChen That's a good heuristic. Unfortunately that sum converges  to $0.444018...$ So perhaps that's an indication that there are no more primes of that form

Comment: So, the reason is the very fast growing sequence. That makes sense. Thank you. By the way, no further prime upto $n=1\ 000$

Comment: Since the numbers you are working with are huge (see $p_n!$ with $n>1000$), are integer computing precision limits out of the question?

Comment: For $n=20\ 000$ , we pass already $1$ million digits. So I do not expect a further prime either anymore.

Comment: I expect a further prime.

Comment: @David Both pari/gp and pfgw can easily handle those numbers (as integers, so exact !)

Comment: With factordb, I will doublecheck my result. Upto $n=600$, the doublecheck is complete.

Comment: Doublecheck complete upto $n=781$

Comment: This is incredibly fascinating! @Peter what program do you use to arrive at your results? Can PARI/GP work for such things, do you know?

Comment: If n+1 is prime then $n!+p_n!+1 \equiv n!+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n+1}$ using Wilson's theorem so at least those values of $n$ are explained.

Comment: @MrPie pari/gp can easily check this but is very slow. I use pfgw, the fastest software for primality testing if the numbers are very large.

Comment: We can also explain other cases such as if $2n+1$ is prime and $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ then $ n! \equiv -1 \pmod{2n+1}$ so again we have $n!+p_n!+1 \equiv n!+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2n+1}$. This explains the values: $n=5,9,21,23,33,39,51,63,65,81,89,95,99,... $

Comment: Let $\alpha_n=\frac{p_n!}{n!}$. Then we see that $n!+p_n!+1=n!(1+\alpha_n)+1$, so plainly the sum can have no factors smaller than $n$.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe not enough for a full answer but nonetheless some remarks. If the number $n!+1$ has some small prime factor (i.e. less than $p_n$) that immediately implies that $n!+p_n!+1$ is divisible by that prime as well and therefore not a prime number. Unfortunately, it is even not known whether or not there are infinitely many primes among $n!+1$ which btw is OEIS A002981. It could be likely that $n$ for which it is prime would be contained in this sequence - $n=3$ is in this sequence too. I've checked myself $n=872$ and $n=1477$ but unfortunately both of them are composite. Also if for some $n$ from this sequence the number is composite, its prime factors tend to be large, for example for $n=11$ we have:
$$11!+31!+1=192119825921 \cdot 42800573104616324673281$$
Which makes it harder to prove anything by using congruences. I am now in the middle of checking $n=6380$. However:
$$6380! + 63647! + 1 \approx 2 \cdot 10^{278107}$$
Is a huge number and it will take hours to check its primality using my old computer. Maybe someone with better access to the computing power can handle it faster? 
Also I would like to point out that the heuristic from the comments should be somewhat improved (but it still provides much insight into the problem) - we shouldn't consider only the probability of being prime (which we can say is roughly $\log n$) but rather take the probability of $m=n!+p_n+1$ being prime and conditioned on the fact that it is not divisible by any prime $\le n$ - it will make the probability higher and can make our sum divergent (however I am not too certain about it, it's just an idea - I don't even know how one would go about computing such conditioned probability in a meaningful way). 
 
**EDIT** 
 
I've recently checked that:
$$6380! + 63647! + 1 \approx 2 \cdot 10^{278107}$$
Is composite. Also, by Peter's comment if we denote by $A$ the event that:
$$m=n!+p_n!+1$$
Is prime and by $B$ the event that it has no prime less than $n$ we have $A \subset B$ and that asymptotically:
$$P(A)=\frac{1}{\log m}=\frac{1}{n \log n^2}$$
$$P(B)=\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log n}$$
And therefore:
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{e^{\gamma}}{n \log n}$$
Which is a divergent series therefore indicating that there can be infinitely many such numbers. However, the sum diverges very slowly:
$$\sum_{n=10}^{1000} \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{n \log n}\approx 2$$
So we shouldn't expect such primes too often. Actually, we have that since:
$$\int \frac{1}{x \log x}=\log \log x + C$$
We can write:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{N} \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{n \log n} = O(\log \log N)$$
So we shouldn't expect many of them even for big values of $N$ and it's hard to check them because the numbers grow so rapidly. I am now in the middle of checking the next number from the A002981 i.e. $n=26951$. However, since:
$$26951! + 312029! + 1 \approx 6.8 \cdot 10^{1578838}$$
It will take "a bit" longer for my computer to check its primality.
 
**EDIT2** 
 
After three days of computation I still haven't managed to check for the primality so I've decided to finally give up.

Comment: Thanks, it is a sincere and honest answer.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1) . One remark how the lack of small factors influence the probability. If a huge number has no prime factor less than $10^9$ , for example , the probability increases roughly by factor $37$

Comment: Yeah, we could technically approximate this probability as $m$ being prime given that it is not an $n$-smooth number so the new probability would be something like $\frac{m}{\log m (m - \Psi{m,n})}$ where $\Psi{x,B}$ is the de Bruijn function i.e. number of $B$-smooth numbers less than $x$. But I have no idea what is the asymptotics of this.

Comment: not n-smooth, n-rough. The probability that a huge number has no prime factor below $n$ is asymptotically $$\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(n)}$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni-constant.